# What am I doing wrong here in NodeJs Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
request('https://www.mobcrush.com', function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statuscode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body)
        var testing = $('#main-content')
        console.log(testing)
    }
});
```

Trying to scrape the website but the console log comes up blank

Comment: Log out 'body', is that pulling anything?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You're trying to log out `$('#main-content')` which may or may not exist. If you're getting absolutely no log, like `undefined`, you may have an error that you're not handling, so the condition is not true and it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine

you have given `statuscode` instead of `statusCode`

```
  try {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('ssss');
      var $ = cheerio.load(body)
      var testing = $('#main-content');
      console.log(testing);
  }
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```